# HtmlEncoder error in Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error when I compile:
Error-CS0103 "The name 'HtmlEncode' does not exist in the current context"

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition and MVC.

The code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/ 

        public string Index()
        {
            return "This is my default action...";
        }

        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 

        public string Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
        {
            return HtmlEncoder.Default.HtmlEncode(
                "Hello " + name + ", NumTimes is: " + numTimes);
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot find HtmlEncoder to add to References.
Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: the code is solid , you probably sending a wrong GET call. 
please copy the url string + parameters that you are sending to your question

Comment: As I cannot get it to compile I can't give you the URL you requested.

Comment: right click on the project and u'll find it in the "Debug" tab in the project's properties

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello " + name + ", NumTimes is: " + numTimes);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot figure out how to properly include formatting for code.  :-(

Comment: I was able to use the above line; however, be careful to remove the extraneous quote after the "numTimes".

Comment: This line worked for me, but I still don't understand why the code in the tutorial didn't work. Is it like deprecated or the library is not available anymore?

Comment: I found my problem to be that .NET Core wasn't correctly installed

Answer (score 3):

you are missing :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders;
```

Comment: That's it! It was in the MvcMovie tutorial on the asp.net site. Thanks!

Comment: Extensions is also missing. I can't add that.

Answer (score 2):

In MVC Core I had to use,

```
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
```

before HtmlEncoder would work.  I also am using VS 2017 RC and trying to follow the MvcMovie tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I could never get the original project to compile no matter what I did. So I deleted it and started over creating a new project.  I used the same code as above.  This time everything worked!

I assume that the project got corrupted somehow.

Thanks to everyone who attempted to help me!!!